# an error of mpi.h that show file or folder does not exist

Tags: c

Everything was good with my script was good, until I convert to MPI program (I should write an MPI program), it shows me: `mpi.h no such file or folder`. I am trying for ten hours and I keep trying, I am reading the question of people about that but unsuccessfully I did not find a solution.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <mpi.h>



static inline size_t PrintListOfPrime(unsigned int n)
{
    size_t count = 0;

    printf("The list of primes:\n");

    for (unsigned int i = 2; i <= n; i = i != 2 ? i + 2 : i + 1)
    {
        int isPrime = 1;
        /* Check if the current number i is prime or not */
        for (unsigned int j = 3; isPrime && j <= i / j; j += 2)
        {
            /*
             * If the number is divisible by any number
             * other than 1 and self then it is not prime
             */

            isPrime = i % j != 0;
        }

        /* If the number is prime then print */
        if (isPrime)
        {
            if (++count % 14 == 0)
                putchar('\n');
            printf("%u ", i);
        }
    }

    return count;
}


int main(void)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    unsigned int n = 50000;

    size_t count = PrintListOfPrime(n);

    printf("\n\nThere are %zu prime numbers up to %u\n", count, n);

    return 0;
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your Makefile or compilation line? Its hard to tell with the provided information.

Comment: An `file missing` error is not related to the code but to the compilation and your files. Please share the compilation command-line, Makefile or any other information about your compiler and the program files.

Comment: What happens if you just omit `#include <mpi.h>`? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: My program is correct, I know but my problem is I should convert it MPI program ( I saw in the net all mpi programs begin with MPI) and I should do this : - Each process will test its share of the cases.
- Each process should print out any primes that it finds in a readable manner indicating which process
found it and the actual prime number found.
- The master process should end with printing a total for the count of the number of primes and the
total amount of time taken to find all the primes.

Comment: This program displays prime number and their amount